# Where is the mediawiki Login page defined?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to change one of the labels on the mediawiki login page from "Keep me logged in" to "Keep me logged in (recommended)" with a link to http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Logging_in#Log_in_problems.  The label is for an English-language site.

I tried

```
grep -r 'Keep me logged in' *
```

but didn't get any results.

Where is the label set?

Comment: Have you searched the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search of Wikipedia's interface pages showed that that text is found at `MediaWiki:Userlogin-remembermypassword`, as in http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Userlogin-remembermypassword.

Answer (score 2):

To find the name of a message, append `uselang=qqx` to the URL query string. E.g. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:UserLogin?uselang=qqx

To change a message, just edit the `MediaWiki:<messagename>` page.